# Why is the only Stack Exchange site where I can log in with Ubuntu SSO 'Ask Ubuntu'?

Tags: discussion, login

What is the reason I can sign up on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) with Ubuntu SSO and cannot log in with it on other Stack Exchange sites?

Why does Ask Ubuntu differ in that case? Of course, I can use Google, Facebook or simply Stack Exchange login, but it isn't the way.

Comment: Check out Gaming. I'm pretty sure that they're the only site that has a explicit Steam icon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSO) the Ubuntu SSO is an OpenID provider which means you can use it on any of the sites. But only Ask Ubuntu has it called out in a button, instead of forcing you to type in the OpenID URL which is `https://launchpad.net/~`*your_ubuntu_username* .